# Transpose number not separated in columns using Bash

Tags: bash, unix, transpose

I've tried the `tr` [function to transpose in bash but it's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) not working. e.g. `tr 'abcd' 'jkmn'`...

The idea is to take a series of numbers:

```
92121
92911
```

and switch them so that they would look like this:

```
99
22
19
21
11
```

Here is a test dataset:

```
echo "92121
      92911
      29222
      22222
      22222
      22222" > ~/Desktop/output.geno
```

I know we can separate numbers using the [cut function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350243/how-to-keep-only-certain-numbers-in-a-giant-number-in-bash).

I feel that I could use

```
for var in 1:96
do
   tmp=$(cut -c var output.geno)
   tr $tmp
done
```

Comment: `tr` is for transliterate, not transpose .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An efficient way to transpose a file in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: You have lots of syntax errors. You can't have a statement before `do`. You're missing the `$()` around the `cut` command.

Comment: in French they were saying that it's "transposition" so I thought it was the same. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)

Comment: You set the variable `tmp` then use `$temp`. Is that typo in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM., the output from the link you share is this: `92121 92911 29222 22222 22222 22222`. Is it possible to stack the numbers instead of having them in a row? Actually, it's just separating the numbers, not transposing anything

Comment: Instead of using `cut -f` use `cut -c`. And instead of `wc -w` use `wc -c`.

Comment: If it helps you `for i in {1..5}; do tmp=$(cut -c $i output.geno | tr -d '[:space:]'); echo $tmp; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@M. Beausoleil: Try:
Let's say Input_file is as follows.

```
cat  Input_file
92121
92911
29222
22222
22222
22222
```

Following code could help in same.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++){array[i]=array[i]?array[i] substr($0,i,1):substr($0,i,1)};MAX=MAX>i?MAX:i} END{for(j=1;j<MAX;j++){print array[j]}}'   Input_file
```

NON-one liner form of above solution too as follows.

```
awk '{
        for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++){
                                        array[i]=array[i]?array[i] substr($0,i,1):substr($0,i,1)
                                  };
        MAX=MAX>i?MAX:i
     }
     END{
                for(j=1;j<MAX;j++){
                                        print array[j]
                                  }
     }
    '   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
992222
229222
192222
212222
112222
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
$ cat file
92121
92911
29222
22222
22222
22222
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '
{   
    n=split($0,F,r)
    for (i=1; i in F; i++)
        a[NR,i] = F[i]
}
n>p { p = n }
END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) 
    {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++)
        {
            str=str a[i,j];
        }
        print str
    }
}' file
992222
229222
192222
212222
112222
```